# Plot histogram and density function

Tags: statistics, graphing-functions, stochastic-calculus

I need to plot a histogram for the data:

```
10.478 7.268 2.775 0.381 0.979 1.226 1.392 4.706
0.003 5.004 2.835 2.441 1.838 10.780 0.010 4.732
3.042 8.817 0.670 1.693 11.576 2.469 9.905 2.265
1.184 0.093 5.187 1.828 7.140 0.136 1.408 6.349
3.717 7.170 0.609 3.084 0.122 3.154 3.574 0.420
```

The data seem to be exponentially distributed. With maximum lokelihood I estimate $\lambda$ to $\lambda = \frac{1}{\bar x} = 0.2808$. Now I have to plot the density function in the same figure as histogram. But i have to scale the density function to let it look well. Here is the histogram with density function multiplied by $\sum_{i=1}^{40} x_i$ and without scaling: [image] [image]

How do I scale it in the right way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: your total probability mass (sum over all possible values) is 1 for your fit. So, scale by the number of data points.

Comment: @Memming, by multiplying the density function by 40 or what?

Comment: Yes, if you have 40 points, multiply by 40. Your histogram integrates to 40.